# Black lines on sprites

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprites

I am having the issue as seen below while using a textureAtlas with libgdx. I haven't found anyone else with the issue so I decided to ask here.

Here is an image of the textures in the game screen: [image]

And to prove it's not a texture related issue, here is the spritesheet with the same background color as the game screen has applied:

[image]

Any suggestions? sorry for the sloppy write-up I am very preoccupied.

Comment: This may be the same problem as [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144367/why-do-i-have-lines-going-across-my-libgdx-game-using-tiled) (haven't used TextureAtlas before so not entirely sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer has to do with alpha channels and the way they were being processed. I removed transparent pixels from the edges and it works as intended now.